# OpenGL equivalent of OpenGL ES 2.0's extension GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm converting some OpenGL ES 2.0 code to run on standard desktop hardware which does not support OpenGL ES 2.0, but only standard OpenGL.

The code uses the extension `GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch` (previously known as `GL_APPLE_shader_framebuffer_fetch`), which allows the fragment shader to read the 'previous' fragment color through:

```
mediump vec4 lastFragColor = gl_LastFragData[0];
```

This can be used to do custom (i.e. programmable) blending.

**Is there an equivalent for this in OpenGL?**

If not, I would have to render to a framebuffer texture and attach this texture to the same fragment shader that is rendering to it.

Comment: What do you need this for, specifically? There might be other ways around the problem you're trying to solve on desktop OpenGL. For example, I was using this extension to write out per-fragment depth values, but you can do that directly in OpenGL so I was able to rework my shaders using that.

Comment: Yes that's the reason I needed it initially, and I was able to work around it the same way as you did, after I had asked this question. Thanks anyway!

Comment: *"If not, I would have to render to a framebuffer texture and attach this texture to the same fragment shader that is rendering to it."* - This won't work, though.

Answer (score 3):

While not being a direct equivalent, glTextureBarrier() on desktop OpenGL (core in 4.5, or through ARB_texture_barrier/GL_NV_texture_barrier) allows (with some restrictions) to read from the same texture that is attached to the currently bound fbo, while rendering to it.

so, while GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch allows you to do something like

```
gl_FragColor = 0.5 * gl_LastFragData[0];
```

glTextureBarrier allows you to do something like

```
gl_FragColor = 0.5 * texelFetch(current_color_attachment, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), 0)​;
```

Both methods read the current fragment color, modify it and then write it back.

Comment: glTextureBarrier is for reading the written value in a _subsequent_ draw call.
In the same shader it should actually just work, if: "There is only a single read and write of each texel, and the read is in 
the fragment shader invocation that writes the same texel (e.g.using 
texelFetch2D(sampler, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), 0);)." See section 9.3 of the spec.

Comment: The question is if you get any optimizations similar to how the extension allows keeping everything in tile-local memory. Not sure if it's relevant either since Nvidia's dynamic tiling architecture is a bit different from the traditional mobile tiled renderers.